# Not able to connect FTP in CentOS installation

Tags: centos, installation

I am installing CentOS in Virtualbox.

I entered CentOS directory without / at the beginning even though you see /Linux/... in the first image.

Then I get an error message as you can see in the second image.

I think the cause of error is the second // in ftp://ftp.riken.jp//Linux/..

I am not able to get rid of one of /.

What could be the reason or how to install from FTP?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/5/os/x86_64 instead of ftp://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/5/isos/x86_64.